# SSAS Tabular Time Intelligence functions

Tags: ssas, tabular, ssas-tabular

I am using a tabular model compatibility level 1200, and I want to use Time Intelligence calculations like YTD, LYTD, etc.
Is it possible to do that on this version of SQL Server Analysis Services?

Is it possible to create a date dimension on SSAS Tabular?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use time intelligence calculations in SSAS. The best place to start for checking DAX support in the version is Power BI, Excel and SSAS is [dax.guide](https://dax.guide/), here for example is the DAX link for [TOTALYTD](https://dax.guide/totalytd/)

[image: DAX Support]

You can create a Date Dim in a number of ways in a DAX format for example using CALENDARAUTO, or import it from you calendar in your source system if you have one. However as you are using SSAS compatibility 1200, you don't get the option of [calculation groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/calculation-groups) (Compatibility 1500), which means you'll have to create a YTD measure for each of the items you need a YTD value for. For more on this subject please see the [SQLBI resource](https://www.sqlbi.com/topics/time-intelligence/) on time intelligence